# Please give me an example $d:C[\mathbb{R}]\times‎ C[\mathbb{R}]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Such that:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

I need an example $d$ such that:
$$d:C[\mathbb{R}]\times‎ C[\mathbb{R}]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ 
$$C[\mathbb{R}]=\lbrace f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\ | \ f ‎‎\text{is differentiable on }‎\mathbb{R}\rbrace$$
And $\forall f,g \in C[\mathbb{R}]$
$$1.\ \ d(f,g)=-d(g,f)$$
$$2.\ \ d(f,g)=0 \Longrightarrow f=g$$
Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. If you have relevant context (why you want this $d$) or any thoughts of your own, it would be appropriate to add them to your question. Otherwise, since we can only go by appearances, it looks as if you're telling others to do your homework for you.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang This doesn't look like HW to me, just a fun question.  I would like to know in what context it arose, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construction I present below is a little bit contrived, but I think it works. In fact, no differentiability or even continuity is needed; it works on the space of *all* real-valued functions.

Define a function $s:C[\mathbb R]\times C[\mathbb R]\to\mathbb R$ as follows. If $f\in C[\mathbb R]$, $g\in C[\mathbb R]$, and $f=g$, then $s(f,g)\equiv 0$. If $f\neq g$, then define $s(f,g)$ to be any one point $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$. Specify also that $s(f,g)=s(g,f)$, so that one avoids considering the same pair of functions twice and assigning two different points at which they do not agree. (Note that I need to rely on the axiom of choice to construct such a function $s$.)

Define another function $t:C[\mathbb R]\times C[\mathbb R]\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
t(f,g)\equiv\begin{cases}\phantom{-}1&\text{if $f(s(f,g))>g(f(s,g))$,}\\\phantom{-}0&\text{if $f(s(f,g))=g(f(s,g))$,}\\-1&\text{if $f(s(f,g))<g(f(s,g))$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for each $(f,g)\in C[\mathbb R]\times C[\mathbb R]$. Intuitively, $t$ “orders” each pair $(f,g)$ according as which one has a greater value at the distinguished point $s(f,g)$ at which they do not agree. [If $f(s(f,g))=g(s(f,g))$, then $f=g$ because of the way $s$ was constructed, but this doesn't really matter.]

Now define the desired function $d:C[\mathbb R]\times C[\mathbb R]\to\mathbb R$ as follows for each $(f,g)\in C[\mathbb R]\times C[\mathbb R]$:
\begin{align*}
d(f,g)\equiv t(f,g)\times\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left\{\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}\right\}.
\end{align*}
Note that the supremum is always finite, given that the range of the function $y\mapsto y/(1+y)$ is $[0,1)$ on the domain $[0,\infty)$. Also, the supremum is zero if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Finally, the way $t$ is defined ensures that $d$ changes sign when you swap the roles of $f$ and $g$ (but the quantity defined by the supremum remains unchanged).

---

**ADDED #1: Actually, ignore the last paragraph. One can just take the desired function to be $t$.**

---

ADDED #2: Some details about how to construct the function $s$. It is well-known that the axiom of choice is logically equivalent to the [well-ordering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem). According to it, $\mathbb R$ can be endowed with such a linear order $\succsim$ that every non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ has a well-defined least element according to this ordering. If $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ is not empty, let $\min_{\succsim} X$ be that least element. (The purpose of having this ordering $\succsim$ at hand is for one to be able to choose one and only one well-defined element from any non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$.)  One can then define $s$ for each $(f,g)\in C[\mathbb R]\times C[\mathbb R]$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
s(f,g)\equiv\begin{cases}0&\text{if $f=g$,}\\\min_{\succsim}\{x\in\mathbb R\,|\,f(x)\neq g(x)\}&\text{if $f\neq g$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
With this definition, it is not difficult to see that $s(f,g)=s(g,f)$. This implies that the function $t$ as defined above satisfies $t(f,g)=-t(g,f)$ and $t(f,g)=0$ if and only if $f=g$.

Comment: This works as well, and is basically the same idea as my answer above.  One advantage of my answer is that you can avoid the axiom of choice.  My $d$ is not computable, but I would guess that no such function is computable.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Indeed, your answer is more elegant as it gives an explicit choice rule. +1

Comment: Thank you. Examples helpful and I learned. But I need a more simple and more understandable.

Comment: @J.Andy I think Steven Gubkin's answer is simpler and more elegant, indeed (although one does need continuity there). If you agree with me, maybe you could unaccept my answer and accept his.

Answer (score 10):

Pick an enumeration of the rationals $r_1,r_2,r_3,...$.

Let $d(f,g) = 0$ if $f = g$.

Else let $r_n$ be the first rational in the enumeration for which $f(r_n) \neq g(r_n)$.  Define $d(f,g) = f(r_n) - g(r_n)$.

This is well defined since if $f \neq g$, there must be some rational number for which $f(r) \neq g(r)$, since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, and the rationals are dense.